# Get post-user connection p2p_id

Tags: wordpress

I am using Scribu's posts 2 posts pluging to list users connected to a task (post_type) with the following code :

```
 $users = get_users( array('connected_type' => 'task_team','connected_items' =>intval($post_id)) );foreach($users as $user){ ?><?php echo $user->user_firstname; ?>,  <?php }
```

Everything works fine and the result is a row of comma separated Users connected to the task.

My question is how to get the connection id (p2p_id) from each connection of the results

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

So after some more searching i figured it out from the plugins wiki

if anyone has the same question please visit https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Checking-specific-connections